# How to get insert fields from sql?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, apache-calcite, data-lineage

I am using Flink Sql to parse sql's lineage.
I use flink planner to parse a sql as

```
insert into target_table(dest_f1, dest_f2) select source_f1, source_f2 from source_table
```

Obviously, source_f1 is the source of dest_f1.

When I get a CatalogSinkModifyOperation via Flink planner, the CatalogSinkModifyOperation doesn't contains any insert columns information, which means no dest_f1, dest_f2.

How can I get the insert columns' name from my target_table？

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the column information of the target table:

```java
List<String> targetColumnList = tableEnv.from(sinkTable)
        .getResolvedSchema()
        .getColumnNames();
```

or

```java
relNode.getRowType().getFieldNames()
```

If you want to parse the lineage of the flink sql field, you can refer to my open source project:
https://github.com/HamaWhiteGG/flink-sql-lineage